# Query for Employees with Laptops Only

Tags: mysql, database, sql, query

I'm using a MySQL database and trying to figure a query upon 2 tables:

1. Employee table where the status needs to be active
2. Asset table where the status needs to also be active

The asset table represents laptops and desktops. Some employees have a laptop only, some have a desktop only, and some have both a laptop as well as desktop. Also, some employees have multiple laptops, desktops, or both.

How would I write a query to find out which employees have laptops only?

The following is what I have started writing, though my query does not yet isolate employees who have laptops only and I need help revising this for that purpose.

```
SELECT *
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN asset a
ON e.employee_id = a.employee_id
WHERE e.status = 'active'
AND a.status = 'active'
AND a.type = 'laptop'
AND a.type != 'desktop'
```

Comment: Hi, in order to better assist you, it'd be helpful to have sample data. How does the `a.type` column look like? Also, can you explain why you added `AND a.type != 'desktop'` if you already said a line before that you only want when `AND a.type = 'laptop'`?